# updating one position in a slice of slices results in multiple updates

Tags: go, pointers, slice

I learning go and playing with slices but I have a problem

I have a default matrix with ".", but when I try to change the position 0,0 to a "#" symbol all the n,0 position have a  "#", in other words, I start with this:

```
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
```

Modify the 0,0 position with this function:

```
func drawSym(table *[][]string) {
    (*table)[0][0] = "#" 
}
```

And i get

```
[# . . . .]
[# . . . .]
[# . . . .]
[# . . . .]
[# . . . .]
```

When i want a matrix like this

```
[# . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
```

The full code of the program is in playground https://play.golang.org/p/xvkRhmNvdIP

Comment: Your table has 5 rows, yet your code only creates a single row and reuses it for all rows. You only have a single row, used multiple places. If you modify it, you'll see the changes wherever you refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the matrix size does not change, there is no need pass in a pointer to your slice (or slice of slices).

As such you can simplify the creation/initialization of your table like so:

```
func createTable(size int) (table [][]string) {
    table = make([][]string, size)

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        table[i] = make([]string, size) // create a new row per iteration
        for j := 0; j < size; j++ {
            table[i][j] = "."
        }
    }
    return
}

table := createTable(5)
```

the `draw` and `print` functions are simplified too - as they do not need a slice pointer either:

https://play.golang.org/p/KmwynzUj0I-

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as follows so that you would not get the same value at all the rows,create a new row for each iteration instead of using the same.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    table := make([][]string, 5)
    initTable(table)
    printTable(table)
    drawSym(table)
    printTable(table)

}

func drawSym(table [][]string) {
    (table)[0][0] = "#"

    (table)[1][1] = "%"
}

func initTable(table [][]string) {

    for i := 0; i < len(table); i++ {
        table[i] = make([]string, len(table))
        for j := 0; j < len(table); j++ {
            table[i][j] = "."
        }
    }
}

func printTable(table [][]string) {
    for i := 0; i < len(table); i++ {

        fmt.Println((table)[i])
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[# . . . .]
[. % . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
[. . . . .]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is of fixed size, you could use arrays instead of slices (`[5][5]string`). To prevent code duplication and ease the maintenance, you could make a type of the desired length for that matrix (`type myMatrix [5][5]string`) and use that type along your code (`func printTable(table myMatrix)`).

Such as

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myMatrix [5][5]string

func main() {
    var table myMatrix

    for i := 0; i < len(table); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(table); j++ {
            table[i][j] = "."
        }
    }

    table[0][0] = "#"

    printTable(table)

}

func printTable(table myMatrix) {
    for i := 0; i < len(table); i++ {
        fmt.Println(table[i])
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Ok0DBGSfJlA