# Slice mutation behavior in golang

Tags: go, slice, mutation

I am little bit confused with golang slice mutation in some cases. Consider following code:

```golang
    package main
    
    import "fmt"
    
    func main() {
        // creating slice
        s := []int{0,1,2,3,4}
    
        // passing slice to mutating function
        fmt.Println("=========================")
        mutateSlice(s)
        fmt.Println("s, resulting = ", s) // slice not mutated
    
        s = []int{0,1,2,3,4}
        fmt.Println("=========================")
        mutateSlice(s[1:])
        fmt.Println("s[1:], resulting = ", s) // slice not mutated
    
        s = []int{0,1,2,3,4}
        fmt.Println("=========================")
        mutateSlice(s[1:2:3])
        fmt.Println("s[1:2:3], resulting = ", s) // slice mutated, why?
    
        s = []int{0,1,2,3,4}
        fmt.Println("=========================")
        mutateSlice(s[:1])
        fmt.Println("s[:1], resulting = ", s) // slice mutated, why?
    
        s = []int{0,1,2,3,4}
        fmt.Println("=========================")
        mutateSlice(s[:1:2])
        fmt.Println("s[:1], resulting = ", s) // slice mutated, why?
    }
    
    func mutateSlice(s []int) {
        fmt.Println("before = ", s)
        s = append(s, 55)
        s[0] = 11
        fmt.Println("after = ", s)
    }
```

I marked in comments cases where original slice gets mutated and cases where it's not. Can someone explain underlying logic of this behavior?

I am using go version go1.16.6.

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate. The "of what" is the slightly tricky part. The thing to realize is that `append` sometimes *uses the existing backing array* (so that in `mutateSlice`, `s` after the append refers to the same backing array as before) and sometimes *allocates a new backing array* (so that `s` after the append refers to a *different* backing array). **There are no promises about precisely when this will occur** so if you make your code depend on that, you've broken your code.

Comment: Nonetheless, given any *particular* Go version, we can find the compiler's call to the runtime, look at the runtime code, and predict precisely when the "allocate new backing array" happens. Currently this is "when necessary only". It is necessary if and only if the slice header's capacity says so. Print out `len(s)` and `cap(s)` in `mutateSlice` and see if you can match up the modifications to the len-vs-cap numbers.

Comment: Just read https://go.dev/blog/slices and https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [updating one position in a slice of slices results in multiple updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69005086/updating-one-position-in-a-slice-of-slices-results-in-multiple-updates)

Answer (score 0):

First, the slice inside `mutateSlice` function scope is a copy of the original slice header.

Second, the backing array of that slice may be reallocated if the slice doesn't have enough room for the new element, thus when `len(s) == cap(s)`. When this happens, the `append` and `s[0] = 11` inside function `mutateSlice` affect the new backing array and leave the original backing array as it was before.

Third, reslicing (`s[1:]`, `s[:1]` etc) keeps the original capacity.

Fourth, three index reslice `[i:j:k]` sets the new capacity to `k-i`

If you print `len` and `cap` inside `mutateSlice` you will see what I mean.

```
s := []int{0,1,2,3,4}

mutateSlice(s) // len(s) = 5, cap(s) = 5, append does realloc, no mutation

mutateSlice(s[1:]) // len(s[1:]) = 4, cap(s[1:]) = 4, append does realloc, no mutation

mutateSlice(s[1:2:3]) // len(s[1:2:3]) = 1, cap(s[1:2:3]) = 2 (3-1), append does not realloc, original array mutated

mutateSlice(s[:1]) // len(s[:1]) = 1, cap(s[:1]) = 5, append does NOT realloc, original array mutated

mutateSlice(s[:1:2]) // len(s[:1:2]) = 1, cap(s[:1:2]) = 2 (2-0), append does NOT realloc, original array mutated
```

Check it here --> https://play.golang.org/p/eiv0nXj9CBZ